# Jupyter Notebook: need to review all cells in a data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter notebook, having a python data frame of 100 columns and 200 rows. I need to manually review every cell in the data frame, but on the browser, it just show "..." when the row or column numbers are large. Can I force it to show every row and column instead of just showing "..."?

Thanks!

Comment: I might also urge you not to manually review 20,000 values.  Obviously I don't know your specific situation, but this is a big part of learning to work with data programmatically vesus working with it in an Excel-like format.  Working with data this way is a skill that takes practice, but once you're comfortable with it it's infinitely more robust and scalable.

Comment: Not sure why you want to check 20,000 entries manually instead of programmatically checking for what you're looking for
EDIT: What @JeffL. said

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must configure the `display.max_rows` and/or `display.max_columns`using [`pd.set_option()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html).

I.e.:

```
def print_all(x):
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', len(x))
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', len(x.columns))

    print(x)

    pd.reset_option('display.max_rows')
    pd.reset_option('display.max_columns')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify how many rows you want shown. You can configure those options in a notebook like this...

```
pd.set_option('display.max_column', 999)
pd.set_option('display.max_row', 999)
```

where 999 is the number of rows/columns to be shown